# Is count(collection) > 1 supported in an Azure Search query

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

Is there a way to do a count on a collections type in a search query? Something like if CollectionsOfIds is an EDM string collection:

```
$filter=count(CollectionsOfIds) > 1
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t directly access the count of elements in a collection. The best you can do is test whether a collection is empty:

```
$filter=CollectionOfIds/any()
```