# Is it possible to query an Azure Search Index for a specified field of type Collection being not null?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I need to query a large Azure Index to find all records where a particular field (being simply a collection or array of strings) is null but I am having trouble trying to use Odata expressions to identify them since apparently this type of data cannot quantify for use in a filter as such:

```
{
   "search": "*",
   "queryType": "full",
   "select": "Email",
   "count": true,
   "filter": "Skills eq null"
}
```

Attempting is this manner will throw the following error:

The operand for a binary operator 'NotEqual' is not a single value. Binary operators require both operands to be single values.\r\nParameter name: $filter

So how might I achieve a listing of these records where the corresponding Collection(Edm.String) is an empty array?

---

```
      UPDATED
```

Thanks guys. Per the recommended solution, the following returns only those collections having records.

```
{
    "searchMode": "any",
    "queryType": "full",
    "select": "QualifiedFor",
    "count": true,
    "filter": "Skills/any()"
}
```

Comment: Please see if this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54027220/is-countcollection-1-supported-in-an-azure-search-query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$filter uses OData:

> The any operator applies a Boolean expression to each member of a
> collection and returns true if the expression is true for any member
> of the collection, otherwise it returns false. The any operator
> without an argument returns true if the collection is not empty.

Source: http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata03/os/complete/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-errata03-os-part2-url-conventions-complete.html#_Toc371341806

as @Guarav Matri said, just use `$filter=Skills/any()`

Comment: Thanks! That's the result I was after